My tsconfig.json file is showing an error when I use exclude; Expected comma
"exclude": [
"filename.ts"
]

Exclude gives the error, and the colon is marked red. Replacing this with a comma adds multiple new errors (including "Expecting a colon").
All examples I see online don't appear to use a comma (unless it's to separate multiple files, which I haven't included), and the chosen files does seem to be excluded so the code works despite the error.
Where exactly is this comma expected?

Where exactly is this comma expected? Impossible to know without seeing the rest of the file.

Thanks, this forced me to look outside the code I pasted. It was missing a comma before "exclude", and after the last square bracket.

I was missing the comma before "exclude", very silly.
},
"exclude":[],

